# How to use window.alert() when redirected to a page that doesn't exist in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    <Route path="*">
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Route>
```

The code above is what I am using to handle all not found routes. I have all routes in switch and for the most part this is working fine `<Switch>`. I was wondering how I would go about sending a windows alert saying something along the lines of "this page doesn't exist" when the unknown route is called. I tried using `render` and calling a function, but that didn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

edit: to make it clear, I am using React framework, javascript, react-router.

Comment: Can you clarify on the language, and any frameworks you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation simply redirects back to `(/)` when the route is not found.

However, to display a `window.alert()` you should consider making a new `NotFound` component and handle the display of the alert on that page.

Afterward, use the [`useHistory`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook to redirect back to `'/'`

See example code below

#### NotFound Component

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const NotFound = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.alert('Page Not found');
    history.push('/');
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>404</div>
  )
}

export default NotFound;
```

#### Existing Routes

```js
<Route path="*">
  <NotFound />
</Route>
```